# Auto/Eager load a directory outside of /app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

In Rails application(Rails 6) I have created a directory in the root of rails application - outside of `/app` folder. I want to try to keep some logic outside of Rails web framework.

```
- rails_root
  - app/
    - models/
    - controllers/
  - lib/
    - tasks/
  - my_domain/
    - check_record.rb
```

check_record.rb file

```
module MyDomain
  module CheckRecord
    def self.call(record)

    end
  end
end
```

Now I am not able to autoload this directory in test(RSpec) and development (rails console) environments.

When I try in `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/my_domain)
```

Tests fail because of *uninitialized constant #Class:0x00007f96e1f1ad90::MyDomain*
Receiving same error when try to access classes in rails console

When I try in `application.rb`

```
config.paths.add "my_domain", eager_load: true, glob: "**/*.rb"
```

I can see all files from that folder being registered in `Rails.configuration.eager_load_paths`,
but tests fail with same error message

When I move this code to dedicated initializer class same output or when running Rails console initializer is not loaded at all.

Usage of the domain types:

```
class MyRecord < ApplicationRecord
  def check
    MyDomain::CheckRecord.call(self)
  end
end
```

How I can eager- or auto- load directory with ruby files outside of `/app` folder?

Comment: What test suite are you using? Is this rspec or test unit tests?

Comment: Rspec is used for testing

Comment: which autoloader are you using classic or zeitwerk?  In rails 6 default will be zeitwerk

Comment: zeitwerk by default as Rails 6 docs says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using zeitwerk autoloader which is the default in Rails 6. In that case your check_record.rb file should be

```
module CheckRecord
  def self.call(record)

  end
end
```

And it should be called like this

```
class MyRecord < ApplicationRecord
  def check
    CheckRecord.call(self)
  end
end
```

Please refer https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#project-structure for more details

Comment: Would be correct to assume, that loading framework "ignores" directories of first level, in my case if I would like to have a namespace `MyDomain` I need to create some "dummy" directory and move `my_domain` inside it?

Comment: yes exactly so your file should be in dummy/my_domain/check_record.rb and dummy should be added to autoload path if you need it that way